# Вывод данных из таблицы MS Access в C#

Tags: c#

Подключена база данных с таблицей автомобили.
В ней имеются 6 колонок: Марка, Модель, КПП и т.д.
Нужно чтобы в каждый label выводились данные из каждого столбца
Например в label1 были данные из столбца Модель 1-й строки
А в label2 были данные из столба Модель 2-й строки

P.S

я тут написал код, который выводит данные в mark.Text (label), но выводит только при нажатии кнопки. Но мне нужно,чтобы выводились сразу, как это осуществить?

```
string query = "SELECT w_mark FROM Автомобиль WHERE w_id = 1"; 
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection); 
mark.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: Это ваше задание, но в чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: Как сделать запрос и вывести данные из столбца и из конкретной строки в label?

Comment: что то сами уже пробовали? Есть какие то наработки? У вас винформы или wpf?

Comment: WinForm. Пробовать не пытался, т.к. проблемы с изучениями баз данных и их запросами/выборками. Пытался гуглить, но конкретного ответа я не нашел.

Comment: вот [руководство по БД](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/), по [формам](https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/1.1.php), ну или вот небольшая статья [Подключение к данным в базе данных Access](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/data-tools/connect-to-data-in-an-access-database-windows-forms?view=vs-2019)

Comment: я тут написал код, который выводит данные в mark.Text, но выводит только при нажатии кнопки. Но мне нужно,чтобы выводились сразу, как это осуществить?
            string query = "SELECT w_mark FROM Автомобиль WHERE w_id = 1";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
            mark.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

Comment: Если у вас есть код, который относится к вопросу, то поместите его в вопрос.

Comment: Если вам надо что то сделать сразу, как загрущилась форма, то вам надо подписаться на событие `Form_Loaded` и там свой код выполнять

Comment: извиняюсь за свою тупость, так как только начинаю изучать C#. Но как это осуществить?

Comment: Нет ничего страшного в том, что вы чего то не знаете. [События в Windows Forms. События формы](https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/2.4.php)

Comment: благодарю за помощь :)

Comment: пожалуйста, на здоровье